# concatenate string of html tags in php

Tags: php, html, string

I want to build table by concatenating string like this
**code**:

```
 $html = '';
 $html .="<tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>    
        </tr>";
 $html .="<tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>    
        </tr>";
```

But I'm getting this as **output**:

```
test test 
test test
```

Instead of table. What did I miss?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm doing this inside of `<table>` tags

```
<table>
<tr><td>Col 1</td> <td>Col 2</td> </tr>

  <?
    //concat code
  ?>
</table>
```

HTML output structure:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xWXG.png)

Comment: Where is table tag?

Comment: I already have the table tag set so I'm doing this inside table tags.

Comment: Then put those codes here .

Comment: sorry just don't be mad :) I just forgot to mention.

Comment: what you looking maybe `border` :D

Comment: :) no. It's not displaying as a table or even formatting as table. the output is a mere text. Updated the question.

Comment: So what do you want actually ?

Comment: What framework are you using?
Something must do a strip_tags before outputting.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add `<table>` tag at start and `</table>` in end of your html.
Do like this

```
  $html = '<table>';
  $html .="<tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>    
        </tr>";
  $html .="<tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>    
        </tr>";
  $html .= '</table>';
```